# Rendering node contents only

Tags: theming

For the purposes of the Cycle plugin I need to render a node without any external buildup, just the `$content`. Is that possible?

Comment: Which version of Drupal are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Drupal 7, [`node_build_content()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_build_content/7) governs the generation of the render array for the node's content:

```
$node = node_load(1);
$content = node_build_content($node);
```

If you take a look at the source for it, you can see how the final render array is built and you can pick and choose what you want in the render array by copying the relevant parts from `node_build_content()`.

For example, if you wanted to just render the node's fields, you might do:

```
$view_mode = 'full';
$langcode = LANGUAGE_NONE;

$node->content = array();

field_attach_prepare_view('node', array($node->nid => $node), $view_mode, $langcode);
entity_prepare_view('node', array($node->nid => $node), $langcode);
$node->content += field_attach_view('node', $node, $view_mode, $langcode);
```

If you did that, `$node->content` would then contain the render array for just the fields without all the extraneous stuff like links or other stuff third-party modules might add.

Answer (score 1):

Great question! This is common when you want to load a node via ajax or some other interactive use-case. My solution is two-fold:

### Create a hook_menu() entry

The `hook_menu()` entry handles the special path you'll likely want in order to create your naked node without disrupting normal usage. In this case I want `node/%/plain` which for node 46 would be `node/46/plain`:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['node/%/plain'] = array(
    'page callback' => '_mymodule_callback',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'node_access',
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

These settings will pass the second URL argument to both our callback and `node_access()`, which handles permissions issues with viewing nodes.

If you think of `node/%/plain` as three parts separated by slashes (part 0, part 1, and part 2), then sending `array(1)` into these callbacks passes along the node ID for them to use.

### Create your callback

```
/**
 * Helper function to render plain node
 */
function _mymodule_callback($nid) {
  $node = node_load($nid);

  if (!empty($node)) {
    // Render
    print drupal_render(node_view($node));
    drupal_exit();
  }
  else {
    // Put 'node not found' msg here
  }
}
```

This function prints out the desired code, then gracefully exits out of Drupal, preserving session data and all the other moving parts within Drupal.

Make sure you use `drupal_exit()`. Using a plain `exit` is bad, m'kay?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just node_load() whatever node you want and print out whatever you want out of it.  Just be aware that drupal saves whatever the user enters, and then relies upon the rendering to clean it up, so, for example, if you have a text field that you want to be plain text, the user can enter whatever he or she wants in it, and that will be saved into the db as is.

Comment: Isn't it safe to use `safe_value` like `$node = node_load(32); echo $node->your_text_field[$node->language][0]['safe_value'];`

Comment: I may have over-read the "without any external buildup" criteria, and I see you are talking D7 here, so I can't comment with any real certainty, but in D6 at least, the 'safe' values are built when either viewing the node, or, as in this case when you are doing something programmatically, by calling node_build_content() after the nod_load(), which, among other things, calls CCK to run check_plain() or check_markup() against that text_field to create, or build up, that field into the 'safe' and filtered/formatted version. (Holy Run-On Sentence, Batman!)

Comment: In either case, D6 or D7, the safe values have been built up however/whenever/wherever they are created.  With CCK in core in D7, it might do this for you in node_load(), I'm not sure, but, for performance reasons, I hope not.

Comment: OK, so assuming I have my isolated content (loaded by node_load or obtained by views_embed_view) - how do I actually tell the renderer to stop adding the outer buildup? This is the point I don't actually get.

Comment: Ahhhhh....you mean the HTML around everything? Just print the fields directly from node_load() etc.  As for  Views, ues it does put a lot of wrappers around things by default.  If that's the case, you need to call the view directly and grab the raw fields and print/do whatever with them directly.  Check out http://groups.drupal.org/node/10129 for lots and lots of examples.  It's for Views 2, but a lot still holds true and will set you on the right path.

Comment: I tried Context to turn off the regions in certain conditions, this seems to be the closest solution. Display Suite's feature of disabling regions did not work (most probably because of my code).

Answer (score 0):

One way to get content on a page without any external markup is by registering a path with [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) and then output the necessary node parts in the page callback function:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['somepage/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Somepage',
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_node_callback',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

function mymodule_node_callback($nid) {
  if ($node = node_load($nid)) {
    $content = 'node content you want on the page';
    print $content;
  }
}
```

`somepage/64` would then (once you have modified the page callback function accordingly) get you the content of node 64 for example.
It's important to use `print` or similar so that Drupal won't add anything else to the page (`return` would get you the result with external markup added).